# Table differences Firefox and Chrome -- table-row

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, html-table

I had to make a website with mostly tables (very old website) a little bit responsive. I've made all my changes and always tested them with Firefox Dev Edition and the [Responsive Design View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) functionality in it.

Now this looks fine in **Firefox Dev Edition** (and **standard Firefox**) but in **Chrome** and other browsers it shows a little different.

This is how it looks in **Firefox Dev Edition**:

[image]

This is how it looks in **Chrome**:

[image]

As you can see my table shows a little different. This is the HTML of a part of my table (table header and first row):

```
<table class="FontNormal">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="right">
                <a href="newtopic.asp">New topic</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="TableHeader" valign="top">
            <td width="500">Topic</td>
            <td width="150">
                <a href="default.asp?DS=A"><font color="black">Last Post</font></a>&nbsp;<img src="../images/sortdesc.gif">
            </td>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Group</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="max-width: 462px;">
                <a href="showtopic.asp?ID=3209">Baxter - Black Piping</a> (0)
            </td>
            <td style="max-width: 462px;">
                14/02/2015 00:29:02
            </td>
            <td style="max-width: 462px;">
                Pharma
            </td>
            <td style="max-width: 462px;">
                BDT Industry
            </td>
            <td style="max-width: 462px;">
                <a href="deletetopic.asp?ParentID=-1&amp;ID=3209">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't have a reset.css . Is there a way I can fix this quickly without a lot extra programming to do?

Comment: Can you provide your css?

Answer (score 1):

You have differing numbers of columns in each row. Ensure the number of columns is consistent and the browsers will be. I think what your seeing is the different handling between Chrome and Firefox for when the number of columns in each row does not match.

```
<table class="FontNormal">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align="right">
            <a href="newtopic.asp">New topic</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="TableHeader" valign="top">
        <td width="500">Topic</td>
        <td width="150" colspan="2">
            <a href="default.asp?DS=A"><font color="black">Last Post</font></a>&nbsp;<img src="../images/sortdesc.gif">
        </td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Group</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="max-width: 462px;">
            <a href="showtopic.asp?ID=3209">Baxter - Black Piping</a> (0)
        </td>
        <td style="max-width: 462px;">
            14/02/2015 00:29:02
        </td>
        <td style="max-width: 462px;">
            Pharma
        </td>
        <td style="max-width: 462px;">
            BDT Industry
        </td>
        <td style="max-width: 462px;">
            <a href="deletetopic.asp?ParentID=-1&amp;ID=3209">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The colspan attribute will makes one cell span X columns so if used as above they will always equal 5.